# Como desativar a Máscara de CEP para salvar apenas os números Digitados ao efetuar um Post - Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, mask, input-mask

Estou usando um componente Remark que possui um `data-plugin="formatter"` no qual aplica uma máscara de CEP no `field`. O `field` possui tamanho de 8 caracteres, mas com a máscara fica com 9 por causa do `"-"` (Ex: 29780-000). Quando salvo o registro o `JavaScript Validation` efetua a validação do lado do cliente e não deixa dar o post por causa da quaantidade de caracteres.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ViewModel:

```
[DisplayName("CEP")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo CEP é obrigatório")]
[MaxLength(8, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
public string CEP { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasEnderecosViewModel[i].CEP" class="control-label lb-cep">CEP</label>
    <input type="text" asp-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasEnderecosViewModel[i].CEP" data-plugin="formatter" data-pattern="[[99999]]-[[999]]" class="form-control txt-cep" />
    <span asp-validation-for="PessoaFisicaViewModel.PessoasFisicasEnderecosViewModel[i].CEP" class="text-danger validation-cep"></span>
</div>
```

Existe alguma configuração ou maneira de fazer com que apenas os números sejam enviados ao dar `post`? Nas aplicações Desktop tem como configurar para a máscara não ser gravada, mas em `app web` eu não sei se tem como. Alguém sabe como me ajudar?

Grande abraço!!! :)

Comment: Você não tem só que mudar o padrão para ´data-pattern="[[99999999]]"´? Ou Você quer manter o traço?

Comment: Pois é @George Wurthmann, em data-pattern eu especifico o formato da mask com o traço para que fique mais fácil para o usuário. Só que o traço ocupa espaço no campo... Gostaria que o traço não fosse considerado... Aliás, que os caracteres da mask não fossem considerados.. apenas os números...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você quer manter o traço, ao invés de mudar sua máscara para `data-pattern="[[99999999]]"` mude o MaxLength do campo.

```
[MaxLength(9, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no máximo {1} caracteres")]
```

E no seu backend você pode tratar esses campos removendo o "-" dessa forma:

```
CEP.Trim('-');
```

---

**Javascript**

Outra opção que talvez seja valida pra você é usar o JavaScript e antes de fazer o submit do form remover o caractere:

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
   var cepApenasNum = $("#campoCEP").val().replace('-', '');
   $("#campoCEP").val(cepApenasNum);
   alert("Meu cep enviado no form é: " + $("#campoCEP").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="campoCEP"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Obrigado @George Wurthmann!!!! :)